# C++11: Regular enums, namespaces, and type safety

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

With `enum class` in C++11 you can't assign an enum to an int without casting. With regular `enum` in C++11, is it correct that it's not type safe and that you can accidentally assign to an int?

What I had hoped to do was bundle helper functions in a namespace with the enum:

```
namespace color {
    enum Color { white, black, none };
    Color opposite (Color c);
    Color is_valid (Color c);
    // etc...
}
```

In that case, I already have the namespace protection with `color::white`, but I do not believe this is typesafe. Is there a way to do it without being overly verbose, i.e. `color::Color::white` with an `enum class`?

Comment: There is no problem with assigning the `enum` to an `int`, the problem is in assigning the `int` to an `enum` (as you could get a non-sensical value for the enum) but [this is not allowed](http://ideone.com/R7cRld) and requires a `static_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of a namespace, what about a class? ([live here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfbda74369a5194f))

```
#include <iostream>

class color {
public:
    enum internal_color { red, green, blue };
    color(internal_color c_): c(c_) {}
    operator internal_color() { return c; }
    color opposite() { return color(internal_color(blue - c)); }
    static bool invalid_color(int i) { return i < red || i > blue; }
    static color validated_color(int i) { if( invalid_color(i) ) throw "blblb"; return color(internal_color(i)); }
private:
    internal_color c;
};

int main() {
    color c(color::red);
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    auto d = color::validated_color(1);
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    auto x = c.opposite();
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    auto e = color::invalid_color(3);
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
/*
    color f(5); // does not compile in c++11
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
*/
}
```

Comment: This is the same as a regular enum isn't it? Meaning, I can still do: int i = color::red; It doesn't offer the type safety that enum class offers.